# Why is the GRUB menu not shown on startup?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on Windows 10, but while starting the computer, it directly boots Ubuntu without any option to load Windows.

How can I get the boot menu and start Windows?

Comment: First, 15.04 is outdated and you should upgrade to 15.10. Did you try to hold the SHIFT key during boot (start holding it before Ubuntu begins to load) to get to the GRUB menu yet?

Answer (score 2):

Although Ubuntu 15.04 isn't supported anymore,
that can occur on the supported versions as well.

Open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gksu  
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Place a `#` in front of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

So that it now reads `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

Save the change you've made and close the file.

Now execute this command :

```
sudo update-grub  
sudo reboot
```

Now you should see GRUB with Windows entry.

Comment: Alternatively to the first three commands, one could also use a console editor and simply run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @ByteCommander :  Thanks for your contribution ! I chose gksu, because it might be more comfortable for some users to use gedit and also, because it is good to have gksu installed generally, when you have to run GUI applications with root privileges. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to run a live cd of Ubuntu and install boot-repair.
Open the terminal and copy and paste the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

After successfully adding and updating the repository type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

There you can solve your issues related to boot.

Or try it with Super GRUB 2 disk.

You can download it from [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Then install it in a usb using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/)
Now you could restart your system and make sure it is set in the boot option menu.