# GRUB menu is not appearing after Ubuntu 16.04 install alongside Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 (200GB for Windows and 100GB for Ubuntu). While installing I made a mistake, I think. Ubuntu loads fine and I am able to do all tasks in Ubuntu, but it boots without showing the GRUB menu. I don't want to install again and again to make dual boot work. How can I get GRUB to appear so that I can boot into Windows 10 without losing Ubuntu?

I am not restarting Ubuntu because I don't want to lose Ubuntu now.

The below case looks similar but I'm afraid to try this one.
[Grub menu not appearing after reinstall and boot repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302084/grub-menu-not-appearing-after-reinstall-and-boot-repair)
trying above-accepted answer didn't work. Below are the commands I entered and the output.

```
root@ubox:/home/AIR# update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

root@ubox:/home/AIR# apt-get install --reinstall grub
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  grub-efi-amd64-bin shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/196 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 224798 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../grub_0.97-29ubuntu68_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub (0.97-29ubuntu68) over (0.97-29ubuntu68) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up grub (0.97-29ubuntu68) ...
root@ubox:/home/AIR# grub-install
install_device not specified.
Usage: grub-install [OPTION] install_device
Install GRUB on your drive.

  -h, --help              print this message and exit
  -v, --version           print the version information and exit
  --root-directory=DIR    install GRUB images under the directory DIR
                          instead of the root directory
  --grub-shell=FILE       use FILE as the grub shell
  --no-floppy             do not probe any floppy drive
  --force-lba             force GRUB to use LBA mode even for a buggy
                          BIOS
  --recheck               probe a device map even if it already exists

INSTALL_DEVICE can be a GRUB device name or a system device filename.

grub-install copies GRUB images into the DIR/boot directory specfied by
--root-directory, and uses the grub shell to install grub into the boot
sector.

Report bugs to <bug-grub@gnu.org>.
root@ubox:/home/AIR# update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

root@ubox:/home/AIR# cat /boot/grub/menu.ls
cat: /boot/grub/menu.ls: No such file or directory
root@ubox:/home/AIR# cat /boot/grub/menu.lst
# menu.lst - See: grub(8), info grub, update-grub(8)
#            grub-install(8), grub-floppy(8),
#            grub-md5-crypt, /usr/share/doc/grub
#            and /usr/share/doc/grub-legacy-doc/.

## default num
# Set the default entry to the entry number NUM. Numbering starts from 0, and
# the entry number 0 is the default if the command is not used.
#
# You can specify 'saved' instead of a number. In this case, the default entry
# is the entry saved with the command 'savedefault'.
# WARNING: If you are using dmraid do not use 'savedefault' or your
# array will desync and will not let you boot your system.
default     0

## timeout sec
# Set a timeout, in SEC seconds, before automatically booting the default entry
# (normally the first entry defined).
timeout     3

## hiddenmenu
# Hides the menu by default (press ESC to see the menu)
hiddenmenu

# Pretty colours
#color cyan/blue white/blue

## password ['--md5'] passwd
# If used in the first section of a menu file, disable all interactive editing
# control (menu entry editor and command-line)  and entries protected by the
# command 'lock'
# e.g. password topsecret
#      password --md5 $1$gLhU0/$aW78kHK1QfV3P2b2znUoe/
# password topsecret

#
# examples
#
# title     Windows 95/98/NT/2000
# root      (hd0,0)
# makeactive
# chainloader   +1
#
# title     Linux
# root      (hd0,1)
# kernel    /vmlinuz root=/dev/hda2 ro
#

#
# Put static boot stanzas before and/or after AUTOMAGIC KERNEL LIST

### BEGIN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
## lines between the AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST markers will be modified
## by the debian update-grub script except for the default options below

## DO NOT UNCOMMENT THEM, Just edit them to your needs

## ## Start Default Options ##
## default kernel options
## default kernel options for automagic boot options
## If you want special options for specific kernels use kopt_x_y_z
## where x.y.z is kernel version. Minor versions can be omitted.
## e.g. kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8=root=/dev/hdc1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8_2_686=root=/dev/hdc2 ro
# kopt=root=UUID=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0 ro

## default grub root device
## e.g. groot=(hd0,0)
# groot=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0

## should update-grub create alternative automagic boot options
## e.g. alternative=true
##      alternative=false
# alternative=true

## should update-grub lock alternative automagic boot options
## e.g. lockalternative=true
##      lockalternative=false
# lockalternative=false

## additional options to use with the default boot option, but not with the
## alternatives
## e.g. defoptions=vga=791 resume=/dev/hda5
# defoptions=quiet splash

## should update-grub lock old automagic boot options
## e.g. lockold=false
##      lockold=true
# lockold=false

## Xen hypervisor options to use with the default Xen boot option
# xenhopt=

## Xen Linux kernel options to use with the default Xen boot option
# xenkopt=console=tty0

## altoption boot targets option
## multiple altoptions lines are allowed
## e.g. altoptions=(extra menu suffix) extra boot options
##      altoptions=(recovery) single
# altoptions=(recovery mode) single

## controls how many kernels should be put into the menu.lst
## only counts the first occurence of a kernel, not the
## alternative kernel options
## e.g. howmany=all
##      howmany=7
# howmany=all

## specify if running in Xen domU or have grub detect automatically
## update-grub will ignore non-xen kernels when running in domU and vice versa
## e.g. indomU=detect
##      indomU=true
##      indomU=false
# indomU=detect

## should update-grub create memtest86 boot option
## e.g. memtest86=true
##      memtest86=false
# memtest86=true

## should update-grub adjust the value of the default booted system
## can be true or false
# updatedefaultentry=false

## should update-grub add savedefault to the default options
## can be true or false
# savedefault=false

## ## End Default Options ##

title       Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed
uuid        abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0 ro quiet splash 

title       Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed (recovery mode)
uuid        abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0 ro  single

title       Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.10.0-28-generic
uuid        abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic root=UUID=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0 ro quiet splash 
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic

title       Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.10.0-28-generic (recovery mode)
uuid        abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic root=UUID=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0 ro  single
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic

title       Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-112-generic
uuid        abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=UUID=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0 ro quiet splash 
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic

title       Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-112-generic (recovery mode)
uuid        abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=UUID=abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0 ro  single
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic

title       Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, memtest86+
uuid        abd3a19c-fed3-4cb7-98e3-63fd5c07ccf0
kernel      /boot/memtest86+.bin

### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
```

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? It looks like you may have opted to removed Windows during the installation of Ubuntu. In that case there would be no Windows installation left to boot. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/749292/228100. Can you please try boot-repair and post the info here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Tring boot info, will update. Meanwhile, I tried other easy options. Dint work so far.

Comment: @AIR you should definitely update your question with the things you've tried and what outcomes each produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct command `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` to show grub menu on boot, but to execute, you need access to Windows OS.

The steps are:

- Boot into Windows OS
- Combine <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> together and type `cmd` to open command prompt.
- Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`and hit enter

P.S : To get dual boot working fine on my dell laptop, I took help of this link [dual boot windows and ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) and I followed above steps too for setting up the grub menu and it worked.

Also, the solution listed as right in your link works. So, give it a try. If you get access to grub through that you can boot into windows and then follow steps listed above to be on a safe side.

Comment: how to boot into windows os ?

Comment: first try the solution marked right in the link you shared. If you get access to your grub, you can then boot into windows and follow up the steps just to ensure grub is created.

The steps worked for my entire team of 100 people so I can assure you of its authenticity.

Comment: cool. fingers crossed. trying it out.

Comment: sure. mark the answer as correct if it works for you so that even others can benefit from it. 
waiting for updates.

Comment: I tried this, please check the updated answer.

Comment: looks like the mistake you mentioned costed you Windows partition completely as stated by other experts in above comments as well. Now you can either clean format your hard disk to reinstall Windows and then Ubuntu (use the link I gave just in case you wish to dual boot again) 

OR you can also try expert suggestions above. 

I personally feel you will have to reinstall both Windows and Ubuntu again. 

Let me know in case I can be of any assistance.

Comment: I will reinstall :)

Comment: Great. You can refer the answer here in case you wish to dual boot. Also, for creating bootable USB, please use Universal USB Installer only and avoid using Rufus. Also, ensure both 'PTT security' option and 'Secure Boot' are in OFF state in your BIOS.

Let me know in case you need my assistance.
Regards.

Comment: I am using rufus for windows booting is that a problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73491/discussion-between-mann-and-air).